# html input is not editable when added "value" parameter

Tags: html, reactjs, meteor

I am working with React 16. I have an input field that needs to populate a value from my database and I need it to be editable.

If I use:

```
<FormControl type="text" ref="price" id="precio" value={this.state.precioVenta} />
```

the input field populates the value but won't let me edit. I tried

```
<FormControl type="text" ref="price" id="precio" defaultValue={this.state.precioVenta} />
```

but it doesn't populate the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a typically state update issue. Where do you update your state? I guess you need to handle your input change manually:

```
<FormControl type="text" value={this.state.precioVenta} onChange={this.handlePrecioChange} />
```

where

```
handlePrecioChange(event) {
  this.setState({ precioVenta: event.target.value }, () => {
    this.validatePrecioVenta(); // if needed
  });
}
```

And do not forget to bind the component's instance context on the component's constructor to make `this` inside the handler work properly:

```
constructor {
  this.handlePrecioChange = this.handlePrecioChange.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle change. If you simply set the value, it will always be set to that:

```
<FormControl 
  type='text'
  name='precio' 
  defaultValue={this.state.precioVenta}
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
/>

handleChange(event) {
    let fieldName = event.target.name;
    let fieldVal = event.target.value;
    this.setState({...this.state, [fieldName]: fieldVal})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason you don't just use `placeholder` instead of value? `<FormControl type="text" ref="price" id="precio" placeholder={this.state.precioVenta} />`